# Extract image from PDF stream

Tags: pdf

I have a decoded PDF stream, nothing else, that contains 2 different "sections'. The first is text, which I am able to parse using the explanation outlined [here](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Extracting+the+text+from+PDF+documents/23008/). However the second section is basically a long string of floats and the letters `c`, `l`, `m`. Here is a small extract:

```
TJ ET BT 7.9701 0 0 7.9701 303.883 132.067 Tm /Ty18 1 Tf (1) Tj ET Q q /Cs1 cs 0 sc 217.8034 565.2423 m 216.5899 564.9437 215.4236 564.0896 214.8605 563.0871
```

I'm not sure how to parse this. My first instinct was that it could be an image but the literature I've found so far leads me to think that I would find it as a binary stream. Is there a way to find out what this is?

Comment: The explanation outlined there is a simplification. Unless you only deal with very simple pdfs, it won't help you much.

Answer (score 2):

It's a sequence of PDF operations. `cs` is set colour space (in this case to the named colour CS1) `sc` is set colour, in this case to 0 (what that actually mean depends on the colour space), `m` is move to, `c` is curve to, `l` is line to, etc.

Comment: Ok awesome, is there documentation for this? I'd like to build a parser so that I can translate it into an actual image. Or could I insert it in a blank pdf?

Comment: The complete PDF specification is available online.  What do you mean "translate it into an image"? This is a series instructions that draw a vector image. What is your bigger goal? Why do you want to do this? There are already plenty of PDF parsers.

Comment: @benwiggy, I've been looking but not finding the documentation for this. Long story short I was able to extract a stream form a corrupted pdf and I was able to recover the text but now trying to recover the image, that's the bigger goal.

Comment: Google for "PDF Specification", and the top hits are the PDF Spec and PDF Reference from Adobe, which contains all the operators.

Comment: The inline image operator is BI/EI, the data for the image is between the BI and EI. The referenced image operator is Do, it will be preceded by the argument, which will be a name (eg /Im0). You then need to look at the page dictionary Resources dictionary, the /Xobject key will have a dictionary value and that will contain the image name. The value associated with that name will be an indirect reference (eg 10 0 R). You then need to look at the xref (which is complicated) and find the offset in the file of object 10, generation number 0. Or search for 10 0 obj.

Comment: As benwiggy implies, writing a PDF parser is non-trivial; the last reference published by Adobe, before the ISO took it on, is 1310 pages.

Comment: I've been working through it for the past hours. It's indeed non trivial. However, it seems very similar to the svg file format. Maybe there is a way to leverage that part?

Comment: I doubt it, I'm not very familiar with SVG, but I don't think its that similar. PDF is more similar to PostScript in general, regarding the graphics model and the composite objects. The cross-reference table, transparency and a whole bunch of interactive stuff are totally different though.